# How do I make my recursive function read every new instance before proceeding to the next level of the loop?

Tags: c++, simulation, physics

I've got to simulate particles splitting into particles.
My simulate function decides how many particles come off from the split. 
Then calls itself to simulate depending on how many particles it decided to split into.

Here's the code:

```
void Reaction::Simulate(double energy,  TwoVector position )
{
    int RandomNumber= qrand() %3+1;//starting particle
    energy = energy/RandomNumber; // change energy for each reaction
    double time=1.0;
    std::cout<<RandomNumber<<std::endl;

    if (RandomNumber==1){
        LightParticle* i=new LightParticle(energy, position);
        int speed = 3;
        i->SimulatePath(time, speed, i->GetPosition());
        i->GetPosition().Print();
        energy--;
        Simulate(energy, i->GetPosition());
    }
    else if (RandomNumber==2){
        MediumParticle* j=new MediumParticle(energy, position);
        MediumParticle* k=new MediumParticle(energy, position);
        int speed = 2;

        j->SimulatePath(time,speed, position);
        k->SimulatePath(time,speed, position);

        j->GetPosition().Print();
        k->GetPosition().Print();

        Simulate(energy, j->GetPosition());
        Simulate(energy, k->GetPosition());
    }
    else if (RandomNumber==3) {
        HeavyParticle* l = new HeavyParticle(energy, position);
        HeavyParticle* m = new HeavyParticle(energy, position);
        HeavyParticle* n = new HeavyParticle(energy, position);
        int speed = 1;

        l->SimulatePath(time,speed, position);
        l->GetPosition().Print();

        m->SimulatePath(time,speed, position);
        m->GetPosition().Print();

        n->SimulatePath(time,speed, position);
        n->GetPosition().Print();

        Simulate(energy, l->GetPosition());
        Simulate(energy, m->GetPosition());
        Simulate(energy, n->GetPosition());
    }
    else return;
}
```

As you can see from the code, it only goes to the deepest level of one path before moving to the next one. How can I make it follow every path simultaneously?

Comment: For future questions, please make sure your code is properly formatted. Improperly formatted code is extremely difficult to analyze, and thus extremely difficult to debug.

Comment: wow that looks so much neater, thanks

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to represent all the particles in a structure, such as `std::vector` then run `Simulate` on all of then for a single iteration and repeat as many times as you think necessary. Avoid `new`. With a vector you just use `push_back` to add each new particle.

Comment: Off topic: Pretty much every memory allocation you make is leaked. Every `new` needs a matching `delete`

Comment: I don't use `qrand`...guessing that's from Qt or something...anyway, I don't see a condition to get you to the `else return`.  Your recursion will go on forever unless you can get to that `else` statement.  Basically what is the end condition for `Simulate`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you're going to get nearly instant stack overflows with this code.

Your basic codepath looks like this, in pseudocode:

```
func() {
    path = RAND(1, 3);
    if(path == 1) /*DO STUFF*/ func();
    else if(path == 2) /*DO STUFF*/ func();
    else /*DO STUFF*/ func();
}
```

So regardless of whether these steps are "simultaneous" or not, your code never terminates anyways. If you want the code to eventually stop, you should have the random number be in a range that doesn't only output numbers `[1, 3]`.

```
int RandomNumber= qrand() %4; //Will stop when RandomNumber == 0
```

If there's a more explicit condition for when the recursion should stop (like when `energy == 0`), you need to code that in instead.

Your second problem is that it's not clear what you mean by executing all these steps "simultaneously". Are you expecting all paths to be executed in parallel in multiple threads?

You'll need to write something like this:

```
std::thread t1([=]{
    LightParticle* i=new LightParticle(energy, position);
    int speed = 3;
    i->SimulatePath(time, speed, i->GetPosition());
    i->GetPosition().Print();
    energy--;

    if(condition_to_continue_recursing()) {
        Simulate(energy, i->GetPosition());
    }
});
std::thread t2([=]{
    MediumParticle* j=new MediumParticle(energy, position);
    MediumParticle* k=new MediumParticle(energy, position);
    int speed = 2;

    j->SimulatePath(time,speed, position);
    k->SimulatePath(time,speed, position);

    j->GetPosition().Print();
    k->GetPosition().Print();

    if(condition_to_continue_recursing()) {
        Simulate(energy, j->GetPosition());
        Simulate(energy, k->GetPosition());
    }
});
std::thread t3([=]{
    HeavyParticle* l = new HeavyParticle(energy, position);
    HeavyParticle* m = new HeavyParticle(energy, position);
    HeavyParticle* n = new HeavyParticle(energy, position);
    int speed = 1;

    l->SimulatePath(time,speed, position);
    l->GetPosition().Print();

    m->SimulatePath(time,speed, position);
    m->GetPosition().Print();

    n->SimulatePath(time,speed, position);
    n->GetPosition().Print();

    if(condition_to_continue_recursing()) {
        Simulate(energy, l->GetPosition());
        Simulate(energy, m->GetPosition());
        Simulate(energy, n->GetPosition());
    }
});

t1.join();
t2.join();
t3.join();
```

But whatever `condition_to_continue_recursing()` is will have to be decided by you; I don't know enough about your overall task to answer this. Also, this will spawn an absurd number of threads if your `condition_to_continue_recursing` is quite significant; use of a thread pool might be preferred. And all of this depends on you deciding that using threads is ideal for this kind of task, which it's not obvious (to me) that it is.

Your third problem is that this code snippet is littered with rather significant design errors.

```
HeavyParticle* l = new HeavyParticle(energy, position);
HeavyParticle* m = new HeavyParticle(energy, position);
HeavyParticle* n = new HeavyParticle(energy, position);
```

Each of these pointers will leak. Since the objects are only used within the scope in which they've been defined, use of `std::unique_ptr` is probably ideal:

```
std::unique_ptr<HeavyParticle> l = std::make_unique<HeavyParticle>(energy, position);
std::unique_ptr<HeavyParticle> m = std::make_unique<HeavyParticle>(energy, position);
std::unique_ptr<HeavyParticle> n = std::make_unique<HeavyParticle>(energy, position);
```

**EDIT**: Alternately, there's no real good reason why you should be using pointers in this context in the first place. The following code would work perfectly fine with no memory leaks or change to the functionality of your code:

```
HeavyParticle l(energy, position);
HeavyParticle m(energy, position);
HeavyParticle n(energy, position);
int speed = 1;

l.SimulatePath(time,speed, position);
l.GetPosition().Print();

m.SimulatePath(time,speed, position);
m.GetPosition().Print();

n.SimulatePath(time,speed, position);
n.GetPosition().Print();

Simulate(energy, l.GetPosition());
Simulate(energy, m.GetPosition());
Simulate(energy, n.GetPosition());
```

You also probably should not be using `qrand`.

```
std::default_random_engine engine(std::random_device()());

void Reaction::Simulate(double energy,  TwoVector position )
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, 3);
    int RandomNumber = distribution(engine);
    /*... Whatever*/
```

A better design would pass the engine into the function.

Alternative:

```
std::default_random_engine engine(std::random_device()());

void Reaction::Simulate(double energy,  TwoVector position )
{
    if(energy <= 0) return;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(1, 3);
    int RandomNumber = distribution(engine);
    /*... Whatever*/
```

There's a lot more to this, but there's a lot to dig into. Hopefully this will give a good starting point.

Comment: Do you see a reason to use pointers instead of the objects themselves?  For the snippet presented isn't `Particle i(energy, position);` just as good?  Then let the destructor clean everything up.  Great answer by the way.

Comment: One good reason might be if `*Particle` objects are extremely heavy/large, which could risk stack overflow issues simply by allocating too many of them on the stack. Granted, that's an extremely corner case, and I doubt it's a problem for the code sampled here, but at a certain point on that path, we've stopped saying "here are the concrete problems with your code", and have started saying "okay, I'm going to completely rewrite this the way *I* would have done it", which is a greater expenditure of my time. =D

Comment: About as good an answer as the question can get in its state. A case can be made for storing the allocated particles in a tree structure, returning the root, then iterating through the tree to process the results before finally destroying it. The tree can be made to *look* simultaneous with a breadth-first traversal in a single thread and handle the memory leak at the same time.

Comment: user4581301 how would i go about  the tree process?

Comment: [tag:Xirema] just a quick question, does the cout return jiberish when multi threading cause they are all couting simultaneously ? Its not really a big deal since i have to animate it on screen and not cout.

oh and my aim was to create a process like a nuclear fission, so the code would output the position of the first generation of particle, then output all of the second generation then so on rather than just outputting positions for only one path

Comment: @RaketMakhim the standard iostreams only have the most basic of multithreading safety, i.e. they won't crash your program. They make no guarantees as to whether the output will be correct or not. If you do plan to use the multithreaded code, make sure you've spent time properly learning multithreading, as even basic stuff can introduce unexpected errors and mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

The `qsrand()` will always hold the same value when not initialised with a value.

```
qsrand(time(NULL));
ID=qrand() % 3;
qDebug << “ID random: “ << ID;
```

or

```
qsrand(static_cast<quint64>(QTime::currentTime().msecsSinceStartOfDay()));
array<int, 3> arr = {qrand(), qrand(), qrand()};
for(auto i : arr)
    cout << i << endl;
```

Comment: Due to a lack of MCVE, we don't know whether or not Raket Makhim seeded the rng.

Comment: Yeah i did learn that the hard way. But have seeded it now. 

Thanks for reply!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you really want to follow all paths simultaneously. In my opinion the trouble is about breaking the loop. This should be provided like

```
void Reaction::Simulate(double energy,  TwoVector position )
{
    if (energy < minimalEnergy) return;
    if (isAtGround(position)) return;

    int RandomNumber= qrand() %3+1;//starting particle
    // all the rest, but please repair the memory leaks!
}
```

where you should provide a function `bool isAtGround(const TwoVector& position)` and a `minimalEnergy` when your particle cannot further divide (typical limits are the lightest particle masses). It might be that instead of returning if the energy is too small, you might follow the particles path to the ground. But that depends on your concrete task.

By the way it seems strange to me that the energy is only lowered for `RandomNumber==1`.

Comment: yeah i had difficulty getting the loop to break as well. I have a if(energy>4) before all of the code and thought that would stop simulating particles. The  energy is only lowered at 1 because at 2 and 3 the energy is divided equally among the new particles. 

Thanks for you response